# How to get the value of text input and set into ActionLink in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to get the value of text input and set into ActionLink in MVC4?

I want to use GET method to pass the value of text input to controller.

```
<input id="search_query" type="text" class="search_input" />
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", null, new { id = search_query }, new { @class = "Button"})
```

Comment: You need a little bit of JavaScript to handle this. You cannot simple create a Link on server with values that are yet to be filled on client.

Comment: give the name attribute to input e.g: <input id="search_query" type="text" class="search_input" name="search_query" />

Comment: It's a *VERY* bad idea to [send data to a server using GET](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188860/why-shouldnt-a-get-request-change-data-on-the-server).  This is exactly why the HTML Form Element exists and was designed to allow the POST method.

Answer (score -1):

Your view will be like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchMethodAction", "ControllerName"))
{  
    <div style="float:left; padding: 10px 0 0 100px; width:50%">
        Search: <input type="text" id="search_query" name="search_query" style="width: 225px" />
        <input type="submit" id="Search" value="Search" />  
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResult SearchMethodAction(string search_query)
{
   //your code here....
   return View("ViewName");
}
```

Remeber: Your Action method parameter name and input name should be same in this case this is **search_query**

if you want to pass in action link then edit your code like this:

```
<input id="search_query" type="text" class="search_input" name="search_query" />
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Search", null, new { id = search_query }, new { @class = "Button"})
```

Comment: id = search_query cannot be found in ActionLink.